# Exact Filtering devices for Android Market place

Tags: android, google-play

we have an application which is supported on devices having resolution 480*800 and above.So
it is supported in supporting handsets as well as tablets.

the setting used in AndroidManifest.xml are as follows

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="13"/>
<compatible-screens>
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

<screen android:screenSize="large"  android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="large"  android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="large"  android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="large"  android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

<screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />

</compatible-screens>
```

This setting is filtering out lot devices, more interesting its filtering out all the tablets except 7 versions of galaxy tab 10.1.

Instead of compatible-screens, I used support-screens but it was not helpful.
Please let me know the mistake done my end.

Thanks.